# How to remove dc component in DCT?

Tags: image-processing

I'm trying to remove dc component in DCT. I will use it in image. I know that the first component of picture which applied DCT is dc component. But when I changes this value to zero nothing changes. I have a 495x495 image.

Comment: you need to provide a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.